# Is there a built-in function in Python that allows you to check the number of items that are already sorted in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

## Problem description

I am attempting to define a function that counts the maximum number of items in an array that are already sorted based on any given array. For example,
`[1, 2, 3]` should return 3 as it is fully sorted, `[3, 2, 1]` should return 0, and `0, 2, 1` should return 2. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: why would `0,2,1` return 2?  why would `3,2,1` return 0?

Comment: @alexpdev -- Because 0 and 2 are in order, and 1 is not.  `3,2,1` should return 1.

Comment: What have you done on your own?  This is obviously homework; you need to put in your own effort.

Comment: What about `[1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9]`?

Comment: This is not actually homework. This is obviously a problem online that I am practicing myself. This function requires a utility function that counts the sorted elements.

Comment: @KellyBundy For that, it should return 5. (`1, 6, 7, 8, 9`)

Comment: This problem is resolved now using C++. Thank you guys very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is either about:

1. Finding the longest increasing subsequence, or
2. Finding how many elements are already in sorted order

**Code for 1**

```
def longest_increasing_sequence(arr):
    ' Finds longest increasing subsequence '
    n = len(arr)
 
    # Declare the list (array) for LIS and initialize LIS
    # values for all indexes
    lis = [1]*n
 
    # Compute optimized LIS values in bottom up manner
    for i in range (1, n):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if arr[i] > arr[j] and lis[i]< lis[j] + 1 :
                lis[i] = lis[j]+1
 
    # Pick maximum of all LIS values
    return max(lis)
```

*Test*

```
for lst in [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9], [10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60], [3,9,2,8,1,7]]:
    print(f'{lst} -> {longest_increasing_sequence(lst)}')
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 3] -> 3
[3, 2, 1] -> 1
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9] -> 5
[10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60] -> 5
[3, 9, 2, 8, 1, 7] -> 2
```

*Explanation*

Dynamic programming algorithm

- Source: [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-longest-increasing-subsequence/)
- Code complexity O(n**2)

*Improvement*

Greedy Algorithm

- Source: [Greedy Algorithm to Find Longest Increasing Subsequence in O(NLogN) via Binary Search](https://helloacm.com/teaching-kids-programming-greedy-algorithm-to-find-longest-increasing-subsequence-in-onlogn-via-binary-search/)
- Code Complexity: O(n*log(n))

Implementation

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def greedy(nums):        
    lis = []
    for n in nums:
        i = bisect_left(lis, n)
        if i == len(lis):
            lis.append(n)
        else:
            lis[i] = n
    return len(lis)
```

**Code for 2**

```
def count_ordered(lst): 
    return sum(x==y for x, y in zip(lst, sorted(lst)))
```

*Tests*

```
count_ordered([0, 1, 2]) # returns 3
count_ordered([0, 2, 1]) # returns 1
count_ordered([3, 2, 1]) # returns 1
```

*Explanation*

The function counts the number of elements that match before and after sorting.

Comment: For my example `[1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9]`, this returns 2 instead of the expected 5.

Comment: @KellyBundy -- are you saying the OP is actually looking for the length of the longest increasing subsequence i.e. [1, 6, 7, 8, 9] which has length 5?

Comment: @KellyBundy -- solution now giving for two interpretations of the question.

Comment: Yes, see the comments under the question. Their phrasing with "maximum" made me suspect LIS is what they want, that's why I asked. Your current code is wrong. Should use `>=` instead of `>`. And for `[3,9,2,8,1,7]`, it returns `4` instead of `2`.

Comment: @KellyBundy -- thanks for the heads up.  I corrected the code but a different change was needed than using `>=`.

Comment: They were two separate bugs. The `>` one is still there.

Comment: Ah, I see you apparently copied that `>` from geeksforgeeks. And that's why you should never ever ever ever EVER use geeksforgeeks. It sucks sooooooo much.

Comment: @KellyBundy  -- yes, geeksforgeeks is too often incorrect.  But, other sources have the same implementation.  However, I also found a different source with a more efficient algorithmi.e.  O(n*log(n)), which I added as the "Greedy Algorihm".

Comment: I guess both definitions can be valid, i.e., the specific term/problem *"longest increasing subsequence"* can be defined as something other than *"longest subsequence that is an increasing sequence"*. That other source (helloacm) for example does: *"return the length of the longest **strictly** increasing subsequence"*. Geeksforgeeks doesn't: *"all elements of the subsequence are sorted in increasing order"* (so its solution is inconsistent with its definition). And this question even only asks for "sorted".